# Visual Studio 2010 can't find iostream

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I just installed Visual Studio 2010, and wanted to test it out by writing a hello world application.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

After trying to compile this I get this error

> error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory

Here are my visual studio include directories

> $(VCInstallDir)include; $(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include; $(WindowsSdkDir)include; $(FrameworkSDKDir)\include;

And my library directories

> $(VCInstallDir)lib;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib;$(WindowsSdkDir)lib;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\lib

Comment: Related: [Error can not open source file “…”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2974908/3357935)

Answer (score 2):

If you are unable to build a simple hello world application then it suggests that either Visual Studio or the Windows SDK isn't installed correctly. Have you downloaded and installed the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/bg162891)? (note: if you need to build for XP you might need to use the Win7 SDK instead)

I seem to recall that after installing the Windows SDK you may need to 'integrate' it for use with VS2010.  Each version of Visual Studio can have a different default SDK that it builds against.  You *may* need to run the [SDK Configuration Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2008/03/01/integrating-windows-sdk-and-vs-with-new-sdk-configuration-tool.aspx) to register it for use with VS2010.  Alternatively, you might need to check the '`Platform Toolset`' settings in the project, as described [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/rob/archive/2010/09/17/integrate-the-windows-sdk-v7.1-with-vs2010.aspx)

Ultimately, once that is correctly setup then you should be able to build simple C++ apps without any further configuration.

Comment: The Windows 7 SDK doesn't appear to be available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The pages given below may help you:

1.) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx

2.) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hdkef6tk.aspx

`<iostream>` is normally stored in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10\VC\include folder.  First check if it is still there.

the /P compiler option is uese to preprocess `helloWorld.cpp`(say),this will generate helloWorld.i, and then you check to see where `iostream` is getting included.
and the builded log should be helpful as well as using the /showincludes option to show the paths to the include files.

Comment: You might want to explain what it is you've linked to and why this might help.

Comment: Above two links are direction to set compiler option.

Comment: I know what they refer to. I've followed them. What I'm hinting at is how to make this a good answer. Tell the OP what steps he might take to figure out what's going on and how the links you've given help him do that.

Comment: I cant find the header files in that location? There are only four header files at that position. How can I possibly restore all my header files?

Comment: As suggested here, the IDE looks for the dependencies in `C:\Program Files\...` so, when I installed in `D:\Program Files\...`, the dependencies broke.  I just reinstalled on C:\ and that worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Go through the normal easy process of creating a new Project --> Templates: Visual C++ --> Win32 Console Application. If not, search your HDD for iostream and set the include path manually.

Comment: You shouldn't be setting the include path manually for a standard library header. If the compiler isn't picking it up then it suggests either the IDE or the Framework SDK isn't installed correctly. It's bad practice to explicitly set the inclusion path for a system header, whether in the source or in the project options.